# How do i make values appear? Like, in arrays. product[0] and price[0] to be the same? Using loop i think. I have no idea what i'm doing

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2010, loops, combobox

Okay, umm. These are my current codes. idk what i'm doing. I'm trying to create an Inventory System, so that the user can add in products, costprice, retailprice, productquantity. But the products aren't pre-added. So, it's only when i run the Form then i add the products. The maximum number of products that can be added is 10. The cbProduct is like the combobox, i have a few comboboxes, but that can be dealt with later i guess. cause i can't even get something to work... This can display the product into the combobox and all, but when i click the Check button, so that the retailprice can appear, the number that comes out is always the same one (the last number i input). I really hope someone can help me... :)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    string[] product = new string[10];
    float [] retailprice = new float [10];
    float [] costprice = new float[10];
    int   [] quantity = new int[10];
    string display = "";

    private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < product.Length; i++)
        {
            if (cbProduct.SelectedIndex.Equals(i))
            {
                for (int h = 0; h < retailprice.Length; h++)
                {
                    display = retailprice[h].ToString();
                    lblRetail.Text = display;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string product = txtProductAdd.Text;
        cbProduct.Items.Add(product);
        cbProductDelete.Items.Add(product);
        cbProductEdit.Items.Add(product);
        cbProductSold.Items.Add(product);
        for (int i = 0; i < retailprice.Length; i++)
        {
            retailprice[i] = float.Parse(txtRetailAdd.Text);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure that you have chosen the most appropriate title?

Comment: "I have no idea what i'm doing" ?????????

Comment: "I have no idea what i'm doing" LOL :-)

Comment: You should make it clear on what you want. I can feel that you want to display something after clicking the btnCheck. And you have only 1 Label, so what's the info you want to display?

Comment: Your logic in btnCheck_Click is incorrect for what you want to do. You loop through all of the retailprices, but you overwrite `lblRetail.Text` every loop. You need to add them together into `display` each loop, then call `lblRetail.Text = display` after the looping is done.

Comment: I think that you should begin reading some OOP books.

Comment: Since your array is fixed size, you need a **counter** variable to track how many items have been added.  This way you'll know which index in the arrays to place the new item.  In the check routine, just use `cbProduct.SelectedIndex` to access the arrays, no need for loops.  You do need to make sure it isn't -1, however, which would indicate no selection has been made.

Comment: umm sorry, after reading what i've typed, i sound ridiculously unclear and i don't even understand myself hahaha. The information i want to display when i choose a product is actually the retail price, cost price, and the number of products in stock. I have other labels but i just haven't added them in. lblRetail, lblCost & lblInStock. @KingKing

Comment: i think so too. what's OOP? @AhmedKRAIEM

Comment: i think i kinda get what you're saying hahahaha i'm gna try to do smth to my codes now hahaa @Tobberoth

Comment: what's a counter variable? @Idle_Mind

Comment: @MarcellaTay you should really set a breakpoint in your `btnCheck_Click` event and step through it; I think once you will you will have a much clearer understanding of what your issue is and why it's always outputting the same value

Comment: @Saggio okaay i'll try that now ahaha

Comment: A "counter" variable would be declared in the same place as your arrays.  Perhaps something like `int records = -1;`.  Each time you want to add a record you'd increment that variable by 1 (one), thus giving you the next available "slot" in the array to save your data.  It also gives you a way to determine if all the slots are full and you can't add any more records.

Comment: @Idle_Mind ohh. hahaha i think i've seen that before. thanksss :)

Comment: @Tobberoth hiiii. i get what you're saying now. ahaha, umm how do i add them together?

Comment: hahaha.... haha? ha, hah hahaha.

Comment: Did you learn how to use a computer? http://nocreative.fi/creative-thoughts/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/chemistry-dog-no-idea-e1332533698640.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the two answers above. Plus check btnAdd_Click function, remove the for loop. Those codes replace all retailprices in retailprice array with the last price you add, so even if the logic in btnCheck_Click corrected you'll still get only the last price added. Replace for loop with

```
retailprice[cbProduct.Items.Count-1] = float.Parse(txtRetailAdd.Text);
```

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother ya'll. The code works but my array size is limited to 10. When i tried adding the 11th item into the combo box, an error was prompted but the 11th item was added into the combo box along with the first 10 items. Can you please advise me on this ? How to I prevent the 11th item from being added into my combo box? The maxdropdownitems is being set to 10 already. Thanks :)

Comment: hey just wondering 
`retailprice[cbProduct.Items.Count - 1] = float.Parse(txtRetailAdd.Text);`
can you explain to me like, what's it doing?

Comment: add some logic in btnAdd_Click to get amount of item already added, if it is 10 already just call return; without executing logic to add another product.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the for loop around in the button click event and just query the currently selected combobox index to check that specific product value

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother yall. The code works but my array size is limited to 10. When i tried adding the 11th item into the combo box, an error was prompted but the 11th item was added into the combo box along with the first 10 items. Can you please advise me on this ? How to I prevent the 11th item from being added into my combo box? The maxdropdownitems is being set to 10 already. Thanks :)

Comment: Query the current item count if its == 10 then stop inserting items into the comboBox,so only insert if(cbProduct.Items.Count < 10)

Comment: Thanks! :) btw, is there such a code like this
`cbProduct = cbProductDelete = cbProductEdit = cbProductSold;`
Or something that makes the combo box all link together?

Comment: If you want to link the items ie. (ComboBox.Items) together that is not such a good idea, you must understand that will be linked by reference.

Answer (score 0):

To add all of the `RetailPrices` together in the `display` string variable, you would replace the line `display = retailprice[h].ToString();` to `display += retailprice[h].ToString();` and then move the line `lblRetail.Text = display;` outside of the `for` loop.  However this will concatenate *ALL* `RetailPrices` into one string.

If you only want to display the `RetailPrice` for the object selected in the `ComboBox`, simply remove the inner `for` and replace it with the line `lblRetail.Text = retailprice[i].ToString();`

i.e.

```
private void btnCheck_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < product.Length; i++)
        {
            if (cbProduct.SelectedIndex.Equals(i))
            {
                lblRetail.Text = retailprice[i].ToString();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, sorry to bother ya'll. The code works but my array size is limited to 10. When i tried adding the 11th item into the combo box, an error was prompted but the 11th item was added into the combo box along with the first 10 items. Can you please advise me on this ? How to I prevent the 11th item from being added into my combo box? The maxdropdownitems is being set to 10 already. Thanks :)